# How to create Row Sequence Number in ORC tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I would like to add Row Numbering or Row Sequence ID column which will automatically increment row id value. Hive UDF UDFRowSequence can be used but it runs in single reducer. I would like to know is there any other feature in latest hive 0.14 to increment row sequence automatically in oRC.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at the ROW_NUMBER() function in a window covering the whole set. It relies on the data being sorted, but should therefore allow parallel partition processing.

Comment: Hi Simon, Can you please provide me sample on ROW_number() , I couldnot get sample for it. I was using Row_Sequence but the problem is the Identity values starts from 1 only. I would like to have Hive column behave like Identity column in DB